# Creating a recursive function to return integers of the result of an xor operation

Tags: c, binary, simulation

The bitwise exclusive or (xor) operation can be applied to two binary numbers where between two corresponding bits:

- 1 xor 1 = 0
- 1 xor 0 = 1
- 0 xor 1 = 1
- 0 xor 0 = 0

For instance, `1101011 xor 1010101 = 0111110`.

Define a recursive function that takes two integer parameters simulating the two input binary numbers and returns the result of the xor operation as an integer. Call and test the function in the main program. (NB: the preceding zeros of the result may not appear on the display, and this is ok).

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: How exactly are the integer parameters supposed to "simulate" binary numbers?  (Also, I assume using `^` is off-limits?)

Comment: Is 0111110 supposed to be 111,110 (one hundred eleven thousand, one hundred and ten)? (Simulating binary numbers?)

Comment: What have you tried?  This sounds like and smells like homework, not least because you wouldn't evaluate XOR this way in real life.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - I strongly agree it seems to be homework. But that truthtable is how I'd define the xor operation if I didn't want the student to just use built in xor (I used to teach CS). The solution may be asking the student to code using a truth table (that was my initial assumption). Also, the student will need to think quit carefully if it returns the answer in an integer. Having said that, I am less sure I know what the question is since the wording has changed. I think m1o2 has done enough to help get the OP started.

Comment: @gbulmer: I removed the rather extreme apologia preamble to the question (the text of which might make an answer in Java appropriate, despite the C tag, which I didn't change). I altered the presentation, but I left what substance there was to the question unchanged, I believe. There is a lot of ambiguity about what is required in the question as stated. I agree that the truth table is a necessary part of the processing if you're not using built-in XOR and clearly you are not to use built-in XOR (but that alone indicates homework; the demand for recursion suggests that recursion is the topic).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - okay, so the significant change is wording is you, and not the OP. IMHO m102 has helped the OP make useful progress, while leaving enough to room to create their own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you should send the parameters in decimal, then something like this might work:

```
void recursiveXor( int a, int b ){

   if( 0 == a && 0 == b )
      return;

    int old = ( a % 2 ) ^ ( b % 2 );

    recursiveXor( a/2, b/2 );

    printf("%d", old ); //System.out.println( old ); if it is Java

}
```

If the parameters is represented in binary (for example: `recursiveXor(111, 1101)`) then:

```
void recursiveXor( int a, int b ){

   if( 0 == a && 0 == b )
      return;

    int old = ( ( a%10 ) + ( b%10 ) ) % 2;

    recursiveXor( a/10, b/10 );

    printf("%d", old); //System.out.println( old ); if it is Java

}
```

Comment: @m102 - it might be cute if the first one is `int old = ( a % 2 ) ^ ( b % 2 );` instead of `int old = ( a & 1 ) ^ ( b & 1 );`. Then the relationship between the two representations (decimal and binary) is clearer.

Comment: @gbulmer ur right, I'll edit that

Comment: You appear to have decimal and binary switched.  Your 'decimal' code doesn't validate that the digits are just 0 and 1.

Comment: @Honathan Leffler, I didn't understand what did you mean. I assumed that the input is valid.

Comment: The first function is marked 'parameters in decimal' but analyzes the binary representation of those numbers; the second function is marked 'parameters in binary' but analyzes the decimal representation of those numbers.  The comment about validation can be ignored; it is at least semi-legitimate to assume that the input is OK.  I'd also worry about `System.out.println()` because the question is tagged 'C' though the original version of the text did mention Java.  (With the right data structures and declarations, `System.out.println(old)` could be valid C, but it would be unorthodox C.)